# Why does WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx return 31 "A device attached to the system is not functioning."

Tags: c#, com, remote-desktop

I have implemented a Remote Desktop Dynamic Virtual Channel server and client, and when I call `WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx`, it returns false and `GetLastError` returns:

> 31
>   A device attached to the system is not functioning.

I am setting `pAccept` and `pCallback` in `OnNewChannelConnection` and returning `S_OK`.  I don't see any exceptions.  A test using the [`ECHO` DVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540879(v=vs.85).aspx) opens perfectly fine with the same client.

```
internal class DemoWtsListenerCallback : IWTSListenerCallback
{
    public void OnNewChannelConnection(IWTSVirtualChannel pChannel, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string data, 
        out bool pAccept, out IWTSVirtualChannelCallback pCallback)
    {
        pAccept = true;
        pCallback = new DemoWtsChannelCallback(pChannel);
    }
}
```

Why does it error with my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mstsc` expects `pAccept` to be set to 1 for true - the default marshalling of `0xffffffff` (which per the `BOOL` type should be fine) is not interpreted as true.

Use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]` to return 1 for true.

```
internal class DemoWtsListenerCallback : IWTSListenerCallback
{
    public void OnNewChannelConnection(
        IWTSVirtualChannel pChannel, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string data, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] out bool pAccept, 
        out IWTSVirtualChannelCallback pCallback)
    {
        pAccept = true;
        pCallback = new DemoWtsChannelCallback(pChannel);
    }
}
```